# Angular dropdown repopulate

Tags: angularjs

This is my angular js html block

```
<select name="input_type0" id="select-type-CA0" ng-model="webfront.customer_fields[$index].input_type" class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched ng-dirty">
  <option value="? number:2 ?"></option>
  <option value="Type">Type</option>
  <option ng-selected="webfront.customer_fields[$index].input_type == 1" value="1">Textbox</option>
  <option ng-selected="webfront.customer_fields[$index].input_type == 2" value="2" selected="selected">Text area</option>
  <option ng-selected="webfront.customer_fields[$index].input_type == 3" value="3">Radio Button</option>
  <option ng-selected="webfront.customer_fields[$index].input_type == 4" value="4">Dropdown</option>                                                
</select>
```

This is my json format output block

```
webfront{"id":1","customer_fields":[{"id":78,"webfront_id":1,"input_type":2}]}
```

The dropdown value is not populating while i am edit. I am new to angular js i couldn't get the right way to find its solution

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to use `ng-options`, something like this:

Controller:

```
$scope.options = [
    { value: 1, name: "Textbox" },
    { value: 2, name: "Text area" },
    { value: 3, name: "Radio Button" },
    { value: 4, name: "Dropdown" }
];
```

And in your view:

```
<select name="input_type0" id="select-type-CA0" 
        ng-model="webfront.customer_fields[$index].input_type"
        ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in options">
     <option value="">Type</option>
</select>
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1b5y0wc9/2/)

Comment: This is not working. Can you give any better solution ?

Comment: Explain what is not working. If you check the Jsfiddle, you can see it works. You probably mean that you expect something else, so please elaborate.

Comment: By adding this. First option of my dropdown beomes empty

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1b5y0wc9/7/

This is my edited fiddle. Please check the dropdown, it is not populated in right way

Comment: Sorry you still don't explain what your expected result is. Check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1b5y0wc9/8/) and play around a little. The dropdowns are populated as I expect, so what do you expect?

Comment: When changing the dropdown it shows perfect value. But When i change and edit  then the dropdown not populate in right way